# NullPointerException while performing measure() on an inflated view

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater, measure

i'm trying to create a BitmapDescriptor from a view.

this is the code:

```
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)myActivity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

            View myView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.myview,null);

            if (myView== null) Log.d("myViewcheck", "null");
                else Log.d("myViewcheck", myView.toString());

            myView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        102--->   myView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));             
            myView.layout(0, 0, myView.getMeasuredWidth(), myView.getMeasuredHeight()); 

            myView.buildDrawingCache(true);

            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(myView.getDrawingCache());
```

and this is the log og the error i receive

```
04-26 12:07:22.989: W/dalvikvm(19048): threadid=23: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:431)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at it.mypkg.utils.MapPopulatorAsyncTask.doInBackground(MapPopulatorAsyncTask.java:102)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at it.mypkg.utils.MapPopulatorAsyncTask.doInBackground(MapPopulatorAsyncTask.java:1)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-26 12:07:23.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19048):    ... 4 more
```

as myView is not null, could anybody suggest me how to debug my code???

Thank you!!

Comment: do you place this code in `doInBackground`  of asyncTask?

Comment: it's exactly what i've done

Comment: I've moved the code into onPostExecute() method but the error remains the same.

Comment: is that same error? I think this one is different..Post stack trace use pastebin.org and share link

Comment: here you are! http://pastebin.com/XUn82AeE
thanksss ;)

Comment: put this code before measuring `myView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);`

Comment: same issue....nothing changed: measure (even yours) always gives me that error

Comment: It seems your view is null

Comment: myView is dynamically casted to RelativeLayout, so it's not null

Comment: finally i found out the solution: i've read android source code, and the method onMeasure() of the RelativeLayout class tried to use for its children layout parameters that doesn't exist; so i've changed the father's layout type from RelativeLayout to HorizontalLayout...and everything is working now:)